# App is crashing when deleting from UITableView due to self referencing connection

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data

I'm brand new to iPhone development (and first question posted here) and am sort of stuck with Core Data and Table Views.

In short, my app is crashing when I delete a row from my UITableView due to NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate being called on a record that has already been removed due to a cascade delete on a self referring table.

Here is a description of the data model:

There are two Entities; ***Person*** and ***Connection***.

***Person*** contains *name* (String), *connections* (To Many Relationship to ***Connection**->source*, cascade delete rule) and *connectedby* (To Many Relationship to ***Connection**->connection*, cascade delete rule)

***Connection*** contains *relationship* (String), *source* (Relationship to ***Person**->connections*, nullify delete rule) and *connection* (Relationship to ***Person**->connectedby*, nullify delete rule)

The idea being that there are two people connected by a relationship (eg *Mother* or *Son*)

In my TableViewController I implement the following:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
}
```

and

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
    Person *person = nil;
    switch(type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];         
        break;
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        person = (Person *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self configureCell:(PersonTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
        break;          
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        person = (Person *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
    } 
}
```

and

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Here are the sample records I created for testing this:

```
Person *person1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[person1 setName:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Tommy"]];

Person *person2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[person2 setName:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Jane"]];

Connection *connection = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Connection" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[connection setConnection:person2];
[connection setSource:person1];
[connection setRelationship:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mother"]];

Connection *connection2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Connection" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[connection2 setConnection:person1];
[connection2 setSource:person2];
[connection2 setRelationship:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Son"]];
```

When I delete the record at indexPath[0,0] i.e. *Jane* in this example since the view is sorted by name, I generate the following error:

```
2010-10-19 16:09:01.461 HelpMe[6324:207] 
Serious application error.  
Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  
This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.
*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0] with userInfo (null)
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
_Unwind_Resume called from function -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] in image CoreData.
```

The delete seems to correctly generate a NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete for indexPath [0,0] but also then immediately generates a NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate for [0,1] which no longer exists since [0,1] is seemingly now in [0,0] after the delete.

Without the associated *Connection* record, it deletes fine.

I can seemingly work around this by simply calling [self.tableView reloadData] on controllerDidChangeContent instead of implementing begin/end updates and didChangeOnject: but I do not believe this is the proper way to handle this.

I appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved a similar issue this by providing a non-nil *sectionNameKeyPath* to *NSFetchedResultsController* (in *initWithFetchRequest*).

I then avoided sections by using:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return @"";
}
```

Very annoying.

FYI, my issue was this error:

> Serious application error.  An
>   exception was caught from the delegate
>   of NSFetchedResultsController during a
>   call to -controllerDidChangeContent:. 
>   *** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
>   with userInfo (null)

Comment: This saved me so much headache - TY :)

Answer (score 0):

At the top of - `(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject`: I was fetching the entity out of the `fetchedResultsController`.  Well, that really messes up things when you have just deleted the object and need to update the table.  I moved the entity fetch into the `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate` portion.  This then kept me from crashing out.